# In this nested list replace hello into goodbye

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
l = [3,7,7,78,12,[1,4,'hello']]
```

Below Ans dose not shows output :

```
l[4][2] = "goodbye"
print(l)
```

Comment: `l[4]` is 12, which is not subscriptable, so this code would throw an exception.  Did you mean `l[5]`?

Comment: And do you mean it does not show the _expected_ output, or it does not show _any_ output?

Comment: Index 4 has no other list so you can't call `l[4][2]`. Do you mean `l[5][2]`? and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested list [1,4,'hello'] is in 5th index.

you should do:

```
l = [3,7,7,78,12,[1,4,'hello']]

l[5][2] = "goodbye"

print(l)

# Output: [3, 7, 7, 78, 12, [1, 4, 'goodbye']]
```